# Set default value for taxonomy list using form_alter

Tags: taxonomy-terms, forms

how do I Set default value for taxonomy list?
I have tried altering form with the following line included, but it didn't work:

```
$form['taxonomy'][3]['#default_value'] = 6;
```

3 is my VOC ID and 6 TID that I want to select as default

Comment: Which version of Drupal ?

Comment: I am using Drupal 6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) I believe this will work

```
$form['taxonomy'][3]['#default_value'] = array(0 => 6);
```