# Change default Taxonomy value on form via form alter in D7

Tags: 7, forms

I am trying to alter a form with a taxonomy term select drop down field; I want to change the default term selected when the form loads.  I'm altering the form array via hook_form_alter; however, my changes do not seem to be taking effect.  I'm looking for an answer similar to [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/13376/1563) but for Drupal 7.

I'm expecting :

```
        $form['field_mytax_reference']['#default_value'] = array($taxTermId => $taxTermName);
```

to do the job but the form remains with the default specified when the field was created.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked:

```
$form['field_mytax_reference']['und']['#default_value'] = array($term_tid);
```

Clive's answer was a helpful point in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

It'll be something more along the lines of:

```
$form['field_mytax_reference'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['#default_value'] = $taxTermId;
```

If the field is a multi-select you would wrap the default value in an array, but there's no need to set a key for it:

```
$form['field_mytax_reference'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['#default_value'] = array($taxTermId);
```

Have a look at [Why is hook_form_alter() so messy?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/27767/why-is-hook-form-alter-so-messy-in-d7/27784#27784) for a bit more info.